# pytesseract installation problem - Linux mint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, tesseract, python-tesseract

I performed the installation of pytesseract to extract the text from an image but there is a problem with my code that I can't solve, I've looked on several sites for the source of the error but I still have the problem... In the error message it says that tesseract is not installed or not in the path, but I checked the same directory as the error message and the file is there!

operational system:

Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon

Python: 3.9

Code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("./Desktop/screenshot.png")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.9 /home/alex/PycharmProjects/Kbot/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/Kbot/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  File "/home/alex/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 409, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/home/alex/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/home/alex/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 287, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 259, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably checked that there is a file *"/home/alex/.var/app/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py"* there, but ... *pytesseract.py* is only a **wrapper** around the *tesseract* engine you need to install in order `pytesseract` can use it.

### Install tesseract using Synaptic Package Manager

or install it from the command line using

### `$ sudo apt install tesseract-ocr -y`

See https://linuxhint.com/install-tesseract-ocr-linux/

Comment: They must make sure they have the exe as well